# JQuery: Is it possible to make animation of an element without any influence on other elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to make an element without influence on other elements?

For example:
I made an animation which changes size of an element A.
Then element located under the element A is moving down.

Comment: Yes, use `position : absolute`

Comment: If it is OK to overlap the surrounding elements, then use different z-index for the animated element. See [z-index](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp) documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do by giving a `position: absolute` and some careful handcrafting of CSS:

```js
$(function () {
  $("#target").animate({
    "font-size": 50
  }, 3000);
});
```

```css
#animate {position: relative; line-height: 1em; padding: 10px;}
#target {position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="animate">
  <div id="target">I will animate.</div>
</div>
<div>I will stay here.</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store the original positions of the items in the document, then reposition them absolutely on the page and animate to wherever you want them. Once the items are positioned absolutely, they won't affect the positioning of the other items on the page.

```js
$("#animate").click(function() {
  //save reference to jQuery Objects
  var a = $("#a");
  var b = $("#b");
  
  //store original positions
  var aPosition = a.position();
  var bPosition = b.position();
  
  //reposition items absolutely on page
  a.css({position: "absolute", top: aPosition.top, left : aPosition.left});
  b.css({position: "absolute", top: bPosition.top, left : bPosition.left});
  
  //animate top of #a to 100px lower
  $("#a").animate({ top : "+=100" });  
});
```

```css
div {
  height: 45px;
  width: 45px;
  margin: 5px;
}

#a {
  background-color: green;
}

#b {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" id="animate" value="animate" />
<div id="a"></div>
<div id="b"></div>
```